# Question about C# 4.0's generics covariance

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance

Having defined this interface:

```
public interface IInputBoxService<out T> {
    bool ShowDialog();
    T Result { get; }
}
```

Why does the following code work:

```
public class StringInputBoxService : IInputBoxService<string> {
    ...
}

...

IInputBoxService<object> service = new StringInputBoxService();
```

and this doesn't?:

```
public class IntegerInputBoxService : IInputBoxService<int> {
    ...
}

...

IInputBoxService<object> service = new IntegerInputBoxService();
```

Does it have anything to do with int being a value type? If yes, how can I circumvent this situation?

Thanks

Comment: No, but from what's my understanding it would lead to the same. int is just an alias for Int32.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely has to do with `int` being a value type. Generic variance in C# 4 only works with reference types. This is primarily because references always have the same representation: a reference is just a reference, so the CLR can use the same bits for something it knows is a string reference as for an object reference. The CLR can make sure that the code will be safe, and use native code which only knows about `IInputBoxService<object>` when passed an `IInputBoxService<string>` - the value returned from `Result` will be representationally compatible (if such a term exists!).

With `int` => `object` there would have to be boxing etc, so you don't end up with the same code - that basically messes up variance.

EDIT: The C# 4.0 spec says this in section 13.1.3.2:

> The purpose of variance annotations is
>   to provide for more lenient (but still
>   type safe) conversions to interface
>   and delegate types. To this end the
>   definitions of implicit (§6.1) and
>   explicit conversions (§6.2) make use
>   of the notion of
>   variance-convertibility, which is
>   defined as follows: A type T is variance-convertible to a type
>   T if T is either an
>   interface or a delegate type declared
>   with the variant type parameters T, and for each variant type
>   parameter Xi one of the following
>   holds:
>
> - Xi is covariant and an
>     implicit reference or identity
>     conversion exists from Ai to Bi
> - Xi
>     is contravariant and an implicit
>     reference or identity conversion
>     exists from Bi to Ai
> - Xi is invariant
>     and an identity conversion exists from
>     Ai to Bi

This doesn't make it terribly obvious, but basically reference conversions only exist between reference types, which leaves only identity conversions (i.e. from a type to itself).

As for workarounds: I think you'd have to create your own wrapper class, basically. This can be as simple as:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public Wrapper(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

It's pretty nasty though :(

Comment: I was thinking that was the case, but I can't find a reference. Do you know of any msdn link mentioning that variances only work with reference types?

Comment: How about this one? http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx - Use Ctrl+F to find "A couple of important rules to remember" and you'll find the entry.

Comment: Is there any alternative? Java defines for all primitive types reference types too, so instead of doing something<int> I can make it something<Integer>, which would solve this problem.